# How to access item in array in JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

```
string json = "{"httpStatusCode": "OK",
      "count": 10,
      "entities": [
        {
          "responseCode": 200,
          "ResponseCode": 0,
          "headers": null,
          "Headers": null,
          "content": "name1"
        },
        {
          "responseCode": 200,
          "ResponseCode": 0,
          "headers": null,
          "Headers": null,
          "content": "name2"
        }
      ]
    }"
```

I use this piece of code and can not print out the value of "content" (name1, name2), it will just skip the if statement

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach (var element in o["entities"])
    {
        foreach(var ob in element)
        {
            if(ob.toString() == "content")
                Console.WriteLine(ob);
        }
    }
```

So, how can I print out the name1 and name2? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the debugger to step through the code to verify things are what you expect them to be?

Comment: Please add a library you use for parsing JSON in your question and tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your example code uses Newtonsoft.Json library.

A few modifications to your code could actually make your code work.
You need to search your JSON for a property named "content". For this purpose cast your `JToken` to `JProperty` type. Then you can access its name and value like this:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach (var element in o["entities"])
{
    foreach (var ob in element)
    {
        if (ob is JProperty prop && prop.Name == "content")
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```